# Is there a way to substitute single spaces in a string with underscore (or any other symbol)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can write a def function to do this task. But, I wanted to know if there is any way I can execute this task in a single line like similar to `string.replace('a',' ')`

```
input  = "This   is a   regular text"

output = "This   is_a   regular_text"
```

Comment: So you want to join two words together, starting from 2nd word @EdwinVarghese ?

Comment: Devesh, wherever there is a single space between words, I want to impute that with an underscore. It doesn't matter where the word starts from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regex to match single spaces between words and replace them with underscore:

```
import re

inp  = "This   is a   regular text"
print(re.sub(r'(?<! ) (?! )', '_', inp))

# This   is_a   regular_text
```

Comment: Great. It worked. I am totally new to regex. Thanks for the answering so fast @Austin

Comment: Note that the parentheses in the regex is unnecessary.

Comment: @Austin for a reason  `- crappy    regular text` did not become `-_crappy  regular_text`  It's not taking hyphens. Can you help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

My take on your problem is that you want to interpolate spaces between words which are *even* with an underscore, instead of whitespace.  This means that the second and fourth spaces would be replaced with underscore.

We can try splitting the input string on `(\s+)`, which will preserve the text and the whitespace.  Then, iterate the resulting list and interpolate underscore for the even spaces.

```
input = "This   is a   regular text"
parts = re.split(r'(\s+)', input)
output = ""

for i in range(0, len(parts)):
    if (i+1) % 4 == 0:
        output = output + "_"
    else:
        output = output + parts[i]

print(output)
```

This outputs:

```
This   is_a   regular_text
```